# upgrade error : illegal package name `doc-base/noawait'

Tags: command-line, upgrade, update-manager, usb-creator

I cannot download anything or upgrade my system. I get the following error message:

```
dpkg: file triggers record mentions illegal package name `doc-base/noawait' (for interest in file `/usr/share/doc-base'): character `/' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I also cannot use USB creator to do fresh install as my system fails to load bootloaders.

Please help

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
CURKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
LINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METALINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $LINUXPKG |grep -vE $METALINUXPKG|grep -v $CURKERNEL)
YELLOW="\033[1;33m"
RED="\033[0;31m"
ENDCOLOR="\033[0m"

if [ $USER != root ]; then
  echo -e $RED"Error: must be root"
  echo -e $YELLOW"Exiting..."$ENDCOLOR
  exit 0
fi
clear
echo -e $YELLOW"Cleaning apt cache..."$ENDCOLOR
aptitude clean

echo -e $YELLOW"Removing old config files..."$ENDCOLOR
sudo aptitude purge $OLDCONF
clear
echo -e $YELLOW"Removing old kernels..."$ENDCOLOR
sudo aptitude purge $OLDKERNELS

echo -e $YELLOW"Emptying the trash..."$ENDCOLOR
rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
```

Save it as `troubleshooter.sh`.
Then, use these commands:

```
chmod 700 troubleshooter.sh  
sudo ./troubleshooter.sh
```

Let me know what happens after that.